# osx: how to update autoconf version for thrift

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard

after installing thrift, i've executed:

```
$ sh bootstrap.sh 

Configuring for:
PHP Api Version:         20090626
Zend Module Api No:      20090626
Zend Extension Api No:   220090626
configure.ac:20: error: Autoconf version 2.65 or higher is required
configure.ac:20: the top level
autom4te: /usr/bin/gm4 failed with exit status: 63
autoscan: /usr/bin/autom4te failed with exit status: 6
```

this obviously say that my autoconf is obsolete. I've searched around and there are no tutorial that says how.

I'm on OSX 10.6.7

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can instead install thrift using [Homebrew](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew) — it knows how to properly handle dependencies:

```
$ brew info thrift
thrift 0.6.1
http://incubator.apache.org/thrift/
Depends on: boost
Not installed
```

---

If that won't work for you, you can install `autoconf` using [Fink](http://pdb.finkproject.org/pdb/browse.php?summary=autoconf) (although that version seems to be too old at the moment) or [MacPorts](http://www.macports.org/ports.php?by=name&substr=autoconf).

All of these programs are Unix package managers specifically for ports to Mac OS X.

Comment: thanks @daniel beck. can you give more details on how to do an update using macports or fink? im a noob in using unix

Comment: @sheeks06 I don't use them, but you need to download and install Apple's Developer Tools (either the commercial Xcode 4 via the App Store, or the free Xcode 3.x after registering for free at developer.apple.com), then install Macports, then open `/Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app` and enter `sudo port install thrift`. I suggest you use Homebrew instead if Thrift 0.6.1 works for you. Homebrew installation is [dead simple](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/wiki/installation), and afterwards, just enter `brew install thrift` in Terminal and wait until done.

Comment: @sheeks Did it work?

Comment: yes sir. worked perfectly. actually i uninstalled macports then installed everything using brew. cassandra and thrift. and its done now :)

Comment: seems that macports can also be used using this technique.